Deploy llama3 on cloud and use it in a Java app
I have a custom llama3:8b model which I have created using a model file with specific instructions. I need steps/resources to do the following which I could not find:

Deploy this llama model on cloud and have it running

Use this model in a Java app, either by using it as a library, or wrapping this model in a REST service and calling that service. Any way works for me


